# In SQL can I join data using a like or contains clause to exclude some values?

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am working on a project to build some queries from Google Analytics data in BigQuery to replicate some reports for one particular KPI, I have a table with a list of sites that I need to have excluded from the Google Analytics data in order to get the correct metric.

My list might have something such as:
*sitename.com*

However I need to match this to the eventLabel column in BigQuery where the URL could come back as:
*http://sitename.com/subpage/extra-subpage*

I can't do a Not In as this requires a direct match, I have tried using a like statement however I get the following error

```
Scalar subquery produced more than one element
```

I'm not really sure how else to proceed and am wondering if I need to do a query that say does the string match (as i can get it to work if i use an inner join and then use this new table to do the exclusions as I can keep the eventLabel and then do my Not In based on that?

```
SELECT Distinct
h.eventinfo.eventAction  eventAction,
h.eventinfo.eventlabel eventlabel

FROM `projectName.ga_sessions_*`, unnest(Hits) h 


 WHere 
 _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20190101" AND  FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))

and type = 'EVENT'
 and h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'EventName'

and Replace(Replace(Replace(h.eventInfo.eventLabel,'http://',''),'https://',''),'www.','') 
                                                Not like (select concat(ThirdPartyURL,'%') from `projectName.datasetName.ExclusionList`)
```

I hope the above makes sense.

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

After reproducing your problem the solution is to use `NOT IN` instead of `NOT LIKE` as follow:

```
WITH `projectName.datasetName.ExclusionList` AS
  (SELECT 'label1' AS ThirdPartyURL UNION ALL
   SELECT 'label2')

SELECT DISTINCT h.eventinfo.eventAction eventAction,
                h.eventinfo.eventlabel eventlabel
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`,
     unnest(Hits) h
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20170801" AND "20170802"
  AND TYPE = 'EVENT'
  AND h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'EventName'
  AND Replace(Replace(Replace(h.eventInfo.eventLabel, 'http://', ''), 'https://', ''), 'www.', '') 
  NOT IN
        (SELECT ThirdPartyURL FROM `projectName.datasetName.ExclusionList`)
```

This is the [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#in_operators) to BigQuery related SQL documentation

Comment: Using ``Not In`` won't help me (or at least isn't doing anything for me as I still get the same number of rows of data) I possibly wasn't clear in the above post.

For example I need to exclude any URLs that have **facebook.com** but these could be actual page links and so could be facebook.com/somewebpage  facebook.com/anotherwebpage etc. so I need something that allows me to just match on the partial string and ignore the rest of the URL.  

Edited: pressed send too soon.

Comment: This means that beside using NOT IN you need to do some more manipulation on the label you want to exclude. So in your example I would use split on the dot and take the first value in the array which will be Facebook. Obviously you might need a more complex regex or split which will cover other cases. The combination of those two changes will help you solve your problem